# WS2ESB 4.9.0 Sample 50: POX to SOAP conversion not working

Tags: wso2-esb

I start ESB using this command:

```
wso2esb-samples.bat -sn 50
```

ESB starts and when I click on list under services it doesn't show any deployed sevrice.like that

```
http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuote
```

Please help. How can I see this service?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant sample is not adding a proxy configuration, It overrides the main sequence configuration.

You can check the main sequence configuration in management console. Visit **main->Sequences** then you can see two sequences name as "*fault*" and "*main*".

You can edit the main sequence and see the added configurations there.

Note - ESB uses the main sequence to mediate unpointed messages to endpoints. So you can trigger it just using "http://localhost:8280/services/"

Answer (score 0):

Go to Main -> Manage -> SourceView . Then you will be able to see the deployed service under main sequence. All the synapse configurations including proxy service, APIs, Sequences can be seen in Source View.